# how does todo mvc example for angularjs do without ng-controller?

Tags: angularjs, todomvc

Every example I've looked at has made use of the ng-controller directive to get things working.

The Todo MVC example at https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/angularjs creates a 'TodoCtrl' controller. But in the corresponding index.html, there is no use of the ng-controller directive.

How is this possible? and why did they choose to do it this way?

Comment: It's defined as the controller for that route in the `routeConfig` section, in `js/app.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the ngRoute provider.

```
angular.module('todomvc', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        'use strict';

        var routeConfig = {
            controller: 'TodoCtrl',//add controller to view
            templateUrl: 'todomvc-index.html',
            resolve: {
                store: function (todoStorage) {
                    // Get the correct module (API or localStorage).
                    return todoStorage.then(function (module) {
                        module.get(); // Fetch the todo records in the background.
                        return module;
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', routeConfig)
            .when('/:status', routeConfig)
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

Comment: To add to that, if you read the official docs for ng-controller, you will see "Note that you can also attach controllers to the DOM by declaring it in a route definition via the $route service." @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController